# Can I use openssl 3.0 envelope RSA encryption without involving AES C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, envelope

I am using Openssl static library to code a program in C++ that sends RSA-priv key to server. I am using Envelope encryption (EVP) for that. Do I have to generate a random key and IV for AES then "envelope" it by using public key encryption? I just want to encrypt my data with public key and send private key to server. My data packets are lesser than RSA key size.

```
int EVP_SealInit(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *type,
                 unsigned char **ek, int *ekl, unsigned char *iv,
                 EVP_PKEY **pubk, int npubk);


int EVP_SealUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
        int *outl, unsigned char *in, int inl);


int EVP_SealFinal(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
        int *outl);
```

Answer (score -1):

Only i know is kind of handshake protocol have syntax ,meaning, ETC. Although need or not need of some messages set by the option.

There are some protocol at tls such like certificate request or ETC.
But never seen "Send private Key".

So, Not sure but i think it is impossible without using more low-level.

And in common, no one want your private-key itself, all they need, when they want to know who are you, is the encrypted message which encrypted with kind of random number by your private key or Key of both have.

I mean if you need to provide private key, then what you try to connect is not just common, but your own or your company's own or ETC.

So to answered that question, i think you should give more information.
I mean you should follow your own process-logic or your company's process-logic.